# Java code multiplication table labels on top

Tags: java

I can't seem to get my code to look like the multiplication table in the picture I linked below. I need to have the numbers above the "-------" in my table. I have labels on the side but no matter how much I try it seems I cannot get labels on the top.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbO0g.jpg

```
public class MultiplicationTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tableSize = 10;
    printMultiplicationTable(tableSize);
}

public static void printMultiplicationTable(int tableSize) {
    System.out.format("      ");
    for(int a = 1; a<=tableSize;a++ ) {
        System.out.format("%4d",a);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

    for(int a = 1 ;a<=tableSize;a++) {
        System.out.format("%4d |",a);
        for(int b=1;b<=tableSize;b++) {
            System.out.format("%4d",a*b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: compiles fine for me

Comment: Adding five spaces in front of the `"------..."` line [fixes the problem](http://ideone.com/ZsGowE).

Comment: You have an issue with your source code. The class name should not have whitespace in between.

Comment: I can fix that and it will let my code run, but when it runs it doesn't look like the table in the picture. I'm missing an extra top label and "---------" above the multiplication table. I'm not sure how to add it